# Firebase Function failing

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having trouble getting a Firebase Cloud Function to execute correctly, and I'm fairly certain it's due to my limited Javascript ability.

Function is fairly simple; all it does is send a notification via FCM. I've tried to follow the recommendations and include .send() lines to avoid eventual timeout. However, according to the logs, the function only ever returns with status "500" and shows "bad" when called via HTTP. The `return null;` was added otherwise the Eslint process would throw `error  Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return` issues.

What am I doing wrong?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) =>{
var topic = 'all';
var payload = {
    notification:{
        title: 'Test Title',
        body: 'Test body'
    },
    topic: topic
};
admin.messaging().send(payload)
    .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
    response.status(200).send("ok")
    return null;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
    response.status(500).send("bad")
    });
});
```

Console logs:

```
8:34:57.492 AM sendNotification Successfully sent message: projects/xx
8:34:57.494 AM sendNotification Error sending message: TypeError: response.status is not a function 
8:34:57.494 AM sendNotification at /workspace/index.js:55:18 
8:34:57.494 AM sendNotification at processTicksAndRejections internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
8:34:57.497 AM sendNotification Function execution took 798 ms, finished with status code: 500
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the contents of the logs that were generated by this function.

Comment: Console logs added.

Comment: You're overwriting the `response` variable from your `onRequest` handler with `response` in the `.then()` callback. Use different variable names, eg `.then(res => ...`

Comment: I recommend you start using a linter (like ESLint) as it would pick up simple mistakes like this. This one in particular is known as [_shadowing_](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow)

Comment: I've changed `response` -> `res` in the local scope, but still having issues. Log now shows entry `Function execution took 893 ms, finished with status: 'crash' `

Comment: Please update the code in your question